# Export triggers only in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

How to export the triggers only from a `mysql` database using `phpMyAdmin`?
I do not have console access to the database, so I can only do that via `phpMyAdmin`.

Answer (score 1):

OK. phpmyadmin have nice [export](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/export) options.

> Step 1

[image: Step 1]

1. Go to export button.
2. Custom - display all possible options
3. Unselect all table

> Step 2

[image]

4. Select structure checkbox in **Format-specific options:**
5. Only check Add `CREATE TRIGGER statement` checkbox in **Object creation options**

Comment: Here I can only export triggers one by one. I have a version of phpMyAdmin 3.5.1. Quite old, I know, but that's what I have.

Comment: @dubliner edit my answer . Possibly this feature may have all phpmyadmin version .  Now you can easily export your trigger(s).

Comment: Unfortunately in 3.5.1 there is not Add CREATE TRIGGER statement, neither on my host's version: 4.0.10.7.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `phpMyAdmin version`
As per http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1403/ dumping only triggers is available

The newest version is 4.3.11.1, released on 2015-03-04.